# How to apply style to element generated by html string in Angular6+

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

Hi I generate a html string, and assign to innerHtml.

The html template is below:

```
<div [innerHtml]="htmlContent"></div>
```

The html string is below:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered text-center">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="text-align:center">Header 1</th>
<th style="text-align:center">Header 2</th>
<th style="text-align:center">Header 3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="w-10">Cell 11</td>
<td style="text-align:center">Cell 12</td>
<td style="text-align:center">Cell 13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center">Cell 21</td>
<td style="text-align:center">Cell 22</td>
<td style="text-align:center">Cell 23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center">Cell 31</td>
<td style="text-align:center">Cell 32</td>
<td style="text-align:center">Cell 33</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to add class for one  element.
The scss file is below:

```
table .table {
   td .w-10{
    width: 10% !important;
   }
   td .w-15{
    width: 15% !important;
   }
   td .w-20{
    width: 15% !important;
   }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You are using a front end data binding framework, there are easier and better ways to inject a table into a div by using the framework features.

Comment: The Problem is in your css selector. Remove the space between  `table .table`  like: `table.table` or just use `.table`, also the same for `td.w-*`

Comment: You need to use `:host ::ng-deep table.table {....`